# Swift: Array vs ContinuousArray usage

Tags: arrays, swift

I've read an article https://medium.com/@nitingeorge_39047/swift-array-vs-contiguousarray-a6153098a5 about performance differences between Array and ContinuousArray. It seems that Array <= ContinuousArray -> so why should I use Array instead of ContinuousArray? And one thing here, Array does not guarantee to store its content in continuous memory - how does it work internally, a LinkedList?

Comment: Every time a ContinuousArray groves so it no longer fits in its memory slot then the whole array needs to be moved in memory which is expensive nd it also said in the article that for value types ContinuousArray and Array behave quite similar so the conclusion for me is that ContinuousArray are useful when the size of the array is fixed and the element is a class.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson and what is the actual data structure used inside Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ContiguousArray](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray) is one of the rare cases where Apple does provide a specialized implementation of a collection for developers to use right away. But as always with optimizations, you should only use it if you *know* (*measured*) that it will give you an advantage over the regular array.

Apple traditionally does **not** expose how containers work internally (unlike, say, Java where you have to pick a [specific container implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html)) so it can change the algorithm/implementation as needed. This is why you have just `NSArray` in Objective-C and `Array` in Swift: the exact implementation is chosen at runtime. For example, there's specialized implementations for single-item arrays, small arrays, and lots of other cases you don't even think about.

Swift *does* guarantee some bounds for certain operations regardless of which implementation it's using internally. For example, `someArray[2]` always has a [complexity of O(1) for reading, and O(1) for writing but may degrade to O(n)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/subscript(_:)-25iat).

If you always use `ContiguousArray` you might deny Swift the ability to use a better implementation. For example, if you add elements, `ContiguousArray` still has to keep the whole list in a contiguous memory region and thus might need to copy around its existing content if there's not enough space in the current region (degrading to O(n)), whereas a default `Array` might not need to do so in this case (still having complexity O(1)).

Comment: thanks a lot for your note, I think I got the idea of this data type